# 'is undefined' using a html-table in a simple for-loop

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, html-table

I'm new to javascript and using the firefox sdk.
I want to simply loop through a HTML-table. When I run the code I get a "Message: TypeError: table.rows[i].cells[1] is undefined" but the loop is working as intended, the problem is that the code after the loop is not executed.
When I replace the variable 'i' with 0 or any other positive integer it works just fine and the code after the loop is executed.
What have I missed? Thank you.

```
    for (var i = 0; table.rows[i].cells[1].innerHTML != null; i++){
        console.log(table.rows[i].cells[1].innerHTML);
        }   
    console.log("this line does not execute");
```

Solved it using:

```
    for (var i = 1; i < table.rows.length-1; i++)
```

Comment: Could you post your html of the table?

Comment: Also, could you show where you declare the `var table`

Comment: A better way to use a `for` loop is `for (var i = 0; i < table.rows.length; i++)`.

Answer (score 0):

You've missed rows with a single cell.

They are zero based so you'll have `cells[0]` being the first `<td></td>` and `cells[1]` being the second one.

In single-cell rows you'll only have `cells[0]` but even if you're 100% sure there's no tables with rows with a single cell, `console.log()` the whole row to make sure. Maybe some browsers have it differently.